# List of last dates of previous months for the past 13 months in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I need a list of last date of the previous months for past 13 months; like
2-28-17
3-31-17
4-30-17
5-31-17 and so on until 
2-28-18
how can i get this in Oracle Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row generator might help:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select last_day(trunc(add_months(sysdate, -level))) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 13;

RESULT
---------------
28.02.2018
31.01.2018
31.12.2017
30.11.2017
31.10.2017
30.09.2017
31.08.2017
31.07.2017
30.06.2017
31.05.2017
30.04.2017
31.03.2017
28.02.2017

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: first day: remove LAST_DAY, truncate the result to 'mm' (month)]**

```
SQL> select trunc(add_months(sysdate, -level), 'mm') result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 13;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------------------
01.02.2018
01.01.2018
01.12.2017
01.11.2017
01.10.2017
01.09.2017
01.08.2017
01.07.2017
01.06.2017
01.05.2017
01.04.2017
01.03.2017
01.02.2017

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also suggest how to get a list of first date of the month for the past 13 months please?

Comment: Surround the expression by `TRUNC(..., 'MM')`

Comment: Remove LAST_DAY (obviously), truncate the result to *month*. I edited my message, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1*(14-ROWNUM))) last_day
  FROM dual
 CONNECT BY rownum < 14;
```